# Need to Validate xml - Help Needed

Tags: java, xml, functional-programming

I have an xml file whose data needs to be validated with 250+ rules, the size of the xml can range from 4MB to 50 MB. Have the following questions.

1. Where the Rules should be defined, as i would like them to dynamically controlled(instead of hard coding)
2. Given the size of the data and input being xml, how should i approach this problem(considering the rules might change etc)
   3.The names of the UI and XML tag names will be different, so when should the translation takes place

Following is the structure of the xml

```
<DATA>
<Parent>
     <Fields>
     //All the data like name, age, height, weight, blood group etc goes here
     </Fields>
     <Childs>
     <Name = 'Andrew' id = 7560>
     .......
     </Childs>
     <Relatives>
     //Relationships
     </Relatives>
</Parent>
     <Children> //For each children it list their details
       //All the data like name, age, height, weight, blood group etc goes here
     </Children>
     <Relationships>//For each relationship it list their details
     </Relationship>
</Data>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would create another XML that contains the set of rules.

As in rules, if all you need is to make sure that the hierarchy is valid and must contain a certain data type,
I would make a "rules" XML that is the complete hierarchy of a perfectly valid XML, containing all nodes with every possibly valid childs and properties, which also contain the required data type as a string value, for instance

```
 <age>"int"</age>
```

Inside your code, you may read through the hierarchy and construct a Tree structure, which can easily validate hierarchy.

If there are much more detailed rules, such as if a node such as  is mandatory and considered invalid if missing, you can set a property such as "isMandatory", which can be read when building your tree, and do a check to see if a certain XML nodes contains the mandatory child!

This will be a dynamic method because all you have to do is edit the rules XML, and your code will be perfectly scalable for future rules.

I've personally used this method before when all I needed to make sure was that the hierarchy is correct and nodes contained the correct properties.. except seeing that you have a whole bunch of rules, you may need a different structure.

Edit:
I would use the DOM parser to parse the XML.
The DOM parsing model is known to be memory inefficient, but will be much efficient in terms of implementation for your situation.
http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/07/31/java-xml-dom-parser-example-tutorial/#parse_known_xml
You can read much more about the DOM parser API in Oracle's website.

Second, it's up to you to get creative with how you want to set up your validation method. A very simple validation XML that may be used for your example would be:

```
<DATA>
    <Parent isRequired="true">
        <Fields>
            <Name isRequired="true">
                <Type>string</Type>
            </Name>

            <Age isRequired="false">
                //Cannot have more than one  age field
                <Rules>
                    <MaxCount>1</MaxCount>
                </Rules>
            </Age>

            // etc etc for other fields

            <Rules>
                //Having name and an age throws error
                <Rule>Name + Age</Rule>

                //Throw error if there is a height element together with an age or a bloodtype
                <Rule>(Age | Bloodtype) + Height</Rule>



            </Rules>

        </Fields>
    </Parent>
</DATA>
```

Method for validation is to start from root node (of the rules XML), and look up all childs. Make sure all mandatory nodes exist in data XML. Make sure all leaf node data type is correct.

Parse all  nodes as a string, and in a similar fashion to solving infix notated int expressions, make sure the childs follow the rule expression.

You don't need to use the same example format using | and +. Be creative and figure out what "rule expression" works best for you :)

Whole point is, there are so many different "types" of rules you might have. For example, one rule may require a must-have node, while one rule might be making sure a certain node does not exist if another one does, and one might be that a certain node cannot exist more than once.
To support so much different types if validations, the structure may end up being complex, but will definitely be worth the effort if you need true dynamic rules (which may end up being reusable, too).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Currently rules are listed as "if node 1 = xyz and node 2 = lmn then throw an error(node 1 and 2 are tag names in the excel)" in some case it can have 5 different elements with and/or conditions. Currently i have three issues                                                1. How to store the rules in xml file, i mean the structure                                  2. How to parse the xml(source)                                                                 3. How to translate the rules to something xml tag names, since UI field names and xml tag names are different

Comment: @DougParker take a look at the edited answer to see if it answers your questions.